# Using IF statements with MySql and PHP error

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have a PHP statment that $_GET's input from a html page and uses that input(customerID) to search through the database for appropriate results. I have that working fine. What i want to do is, if the user enters an invalid customerID, i want the system to give a message and terminate, else if the user input is correct, i want it to be business as usual.

```
$id = $_GET['customerID'];
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password"); 
mysql_select_db("databse", $conn) 
or die ('Database not found ' . mysql_error() ); 
$sql = "SELECT .......
        WHERE order.customerID = $id
        ORDER BY order.orderDate ASC";

if($id != 'order.customerID'){
die('Invalid Customer ID entered');}
else
{   
    $rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn) 
     or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error()); 
}
```

Thats my php code. When i run that, if i enter a invalid ID, it will show me 'Invalid Customer ID entered' but when i enter a vaild customerID, it still shows me that error message. Obviously im making a mistake which im not seeing, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do.  Not.  Use.  `mysql_query`.  It's deprecated, and has been for a while now.  Whoever taught you to use it should have their membership card revoked.

Comment: its for a uni assignment, i cant really change that as i will lose marks @cHao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, *never* trust data from the user, so patch this:

```
$id = $_GET['customerID'];
```

With

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['customerID']);
```

It sanitizes your value (*although it's not completely safe*).

For your main problem,

```
if($id != 'order.customerID'){
```

`order.customerID` is just a string. The correct way to check would be to execute the query first, then check if any rows have returned using [mysql_num_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php), if not display an error message else carry on.

```
$rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn)  or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error());
if($rs && mysql_num_rows($rs)>0){ 
  //query success and rows returned
}
else
{
  die('Invalid Customer ID entered');
}
```

#### Note:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: thanks for that, i was trying to use the if statement like its used in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your logic a bit. First, you need to check if the customerID exists (probably in a "customers" table?) and then proceed with your query.

For example:

```
$customerID = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['customerID'] ); //fixes sql injection 

$queryString = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerID = {$customerID} LIMIT 1";

$query = mysql_query( $queryString ) or die( mysql_error() );

if (mysql_num_rows( $query ) == 0) {
    die( 'Invalid Customer ID entered' );
}

// from here onward you may proceed with your previous statement.
```